# Flipping Signs Using Arithmetic Axioms

Tags: formal-proofs

This may be a dumb question, but I'm in a computer science class called Applied Logic, where we have to develop formal proofs, and I'm very inexperienced with them.

So my question is:

Is there a way to prove that (1*(-x)) = ((-1)*x) using basic arithmetic axioms.
These axioms specifically:

x + 0 = x {+ identity}

(x) + x = 0 {+ complement}

x  1 = x { identity}

x  0 = 0 { null}

x + y = y + x {+ commutative}

x  y = y  x { commutative}

x + (y + z) = (x + y) + z {+ associative}

x  (y  z) = (x  y)  z { associative}

x  (y + z) = (x  y) + (x  z) {distributive law}

Comment: First you have to use your axioms to prove that $-x = (-1)x$.  Then just use associativity.

Comment: You got weird characters in your question text.

Answer (score 0):

$1x+(-1)x=(1-1)x=0x=0$, thus by uniqueness of inverses, $-x=(-1)x$